# Django ModelForm segmentation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've got a model with quite a few fields in it (40 to be exact) and would like to segment the Django form into reusable snippets such that they can be combined or disused dependant on the view.

For example. Let's say a user is on his profile page.  He would should probably have the full form.  However, what if his guardian only has access to (for example) the ability to set his allergies?

It seems like it would violate DRY to create two separate forms in order to generate the guardian view of this user.

Would it be prudent to create a form for each segment that I would naturally see, then extend all of those into a main form?

```
class AllergiesForm(forms.form):
   """ allergies fields 
   """

class ContactForm(forms.form):
   """ contact info fields 
   """

class AllUserInfoForm(forms.Form, AllergiesForm, ContactForm):
   """ what would even go in here if all the other forms 
       are handling their own fields for _clean etc?
   """
```

That way, given a specific view I could show only the pertinent fields OR I could pull AllUserInfoForm from my view and get all of it.

Or do I need to create templates that would manually interact with this form for only the given fields?  And if that is the case I suppose then the _clean methods would need to check permissions before allowing any actual cleaning.

Comment: I believe if you would segment forms in multiple smaller forms, you would create firstly a base form which all child forms inherit from and apply separated needed logic to each concrete individual form.

Comment: How would you submit form? one form submit for all or each form has its own submit and view handler?

Comment: The form could be submitted to self or to a separate updateview/createviw.  The fact that it is only a partial model shouldn't matter as long as _clean and is_valid are usable in the view, which should be the case given I am extending/subclassing from forms.Form... one would think anyway.